# Positioning mdframed box on page using book class

Tags: positioning, mdframed

I'm trying to create a template for a book that I'm planning to write, however, I'm having difficulty placing the box created using `mdframed` at the bottom of the page. I have tried the obvious `\vfill` as you can see from the MWE but I'm all out of ideas.

```
%%Preamble%%
\documentclass[11pt]{book}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[framemethod=TikZ]{mdframed}
    \mdfsetup{%
    middlelinecolor=red,
    middlelinewidth=2pt,
    backgroundcolor=gray!10,
    roundcorner=10pt}
\usepackage[scale=2]{ccicons}
\title{\bf{An Econometrics Primer}}
\author{David Clark}
\date{}

\begin{document}

\frontmatter
    \maketitle
    \begin{mdframed}
        Except where otherwise noted, this work is licensed under \\
        https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-nc-nd/4.0/ \\
        \ccbyncnd   
    \end{mdframed}
    \vfill
    \tableofcontents

\mainmatter
%\include{chapter1.tex}

\backmatter

\end{document}
```

Here is the output from the MWE, of the page in question:

[image]

Comment: you might try it as a `{figure}[b]` with no caption.

Comment: At the bottom of what page? The second page (page just after `\maketitle`)?

Comment: @Werner Yes, that's correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`\vfill` is gobbled when used at the top of a page. You would have to place a blank marker like `\mbox{}`:

```
\mbox{}

\vfill

\begin{mdframed}
  <stuff>
\end{mdframed}
```

or use `\vspace*{\fill}`.